# Wordpress author can add sticky post

Tags: wordpress, sticky

I want to add a new permision to author role. Exactly I want that author can check that post is sticky.

The line above add this funcionality for me but also enable edit others posts what I do not want

```
$GLOBALS['wp_roles']->add_cap( 'author','edit_others_posts' );
```

Anyone know the solution? How can I enable checkbox "sticky post" for author role?

Comment: I found this as well using the `User Role Editor` plugin.  I have to check "edit other posts" in order for users in the role to specify a sticky post.  It doesn't make sense, should be its own permission!  But anyway, appreciate that your post helped me past this problem.